# Making a list sortable even after an Ajax Load

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I'm loading a `li` list like this

```
$('#knowledgeList').load('file.php#knowledgeList');
```

However I also need to make the list sortable:

```
$('#knowledgeList').sortable();
```

That works if I don't Ajax load the items in but if they are loading in via Ajax they are no longer sortable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to apply any JavaScript/jQuery to the component called in via AJAX, you need the object you want to manipulate in a callback function.

```
$('#knowledgeList').load('file.php #knowledgeList',function(){
      $('#knowageList').sortable();
});
```

Comment: Awesome, I decided to make an init(); that I call anytime something is loaded.